# How to stop an image from scaling in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

This was a question asked by a user on Apple's cocoa-dev mailing list, who thought my answer would be helpful on Stack Overflow:

> In XCode/IB, if add an Image View that has the Image property to an
>   image in my project it shows the image scaled to fit the Frame of the
>   Image View. How can I stop this and just truncate it? I want two
>   images on top of each other and just show the top half of one and the
>   bottom half of the other.
>
> I see loads of scaling options in the “Content Mode” Property, but
>   nothing to say “none”. The closest I’ve managed so far is to set the
>   Content Mode to “Aspect Fit” and also set the clip to bounds. This
>   does what I want BUT the centre of the image shows, not the top, left.
>
> Basically, I have two 24 x 24 images placed one on top of the other, I
>   want to show the first half (e.g. 0,0,24,12) of ImageA and the bottom
>   half of imageB (e.g. 0,12,24,12).
>
> Can I do this in XCode/IB? If not can I do this in code?

Answer (score 2):

Create two image views, set their sizes to 24 x 12, and set the *Clip To Bounds* property.

For one view, set its content mode to top (== top-center) or top-left, and the other to bottom (== bottom-center) or bottom-left.

If you turn off the clip property then you'll see that the images draw outside the image view's bounds.